# Recieving information from sockets in multiplayer game without huge delay

Tags: python, sockets, networking, multiplayer

I am working on a multiplayer game in python and pygame and am having issues with the information receiving part through sockets and its making my game extremely glitchy/laggy. Essentially I have a Bloons Tower Defense Battles game and I need to send 1 player's items(balloons, towers, projectiles) to the other player to render them on the screen. I currently am doing this right every frame(frame rate ~120) after I calculate the new values for all of the positions and items on the client side(not good practice but this is just to improve skills):

```
# ... other code ...
self.send_opponent_items(balloons, towers, proj) #sending the items through socket function
self.display_opponent_items() #getting opponent items and displaying them

#display other UI and update screen

self.display_images(self.game_state.get_player_health_ratio())
self.display_game_information()
pygame.display.update()
self.clock.tick(120)
```

Where `display_opponent_items` is defined as follows:

```
def display_opponent_items(self):
    info = self.client.recv()
    balloons, towers, projectiles = info
    # render stuff from info recieved ...
```

This works decently well when I am on my own network using localhost for the client and server and I got the following values for time spent to send and recieve data:

```
Time spent to get data: 0.014797666000000653
Time spent to send data: 2.6499999999707313e-05
```

Not ideal but not terrible. However when I tried this with a ngrok server I got this:

```
Time spent to get data: 0.20153162499999766
Time spent to send data: 3.225000000028899e-05
```

which just makes the game unplayable. As a note, I am currently sending less than 500 bytes of data and when I get this lag so I don't think the amount of data is the problem.

I am just wondering what is best practice to reduce this delay from the ngrok server as I am trying to make this game "online" in a sense. Also, if possible, can I reduce the delay even in my own network for getting data as right now the frame rate is also limited to ~80 fps because its still getting the data in suboptimal time.

I am not a socket tcp/ip expert but I did have 2 ideas for making this faster. One would be having the server calculate all the values and sending them but I still don't know if that would actually change anything and I don't really want to refactor all of my code unless it is absolutely necessary.

Second idea was to create a thread for the sending of the data. Problem with this is that I don't know how to give this thread the new values of all my items as they update every frame. I also don't know if this would do anything but I wanted to give it a try as it seemed like my best bet.

I am trying to do this using only socket library so, although I'm not sure if they will help, but I don't want to use select or socketserver or any of that. How do bigger games do this with so many players and so many things to render, while letting you keep such a high frame rate while I am having trouble getting 80 fps on my own network?

Comment: This is a pretty big, multifaceted question. Generally though, what you're looking to do is called "netcode". There's a lot of tricks and techniques that have been developed over the past several decades in regards to making good netcode, and so I suggest tapping into that resource and doing research on it. There's [books on the subject](https://www.amazon.com/Multiplayer-Game-Programming-Architecting-Networked/dp/0134034309), and countless tutorials and such. I think that by learning about netcode in general you'll learn a lot of things that can help you with this specific project.

Comment: If you're using TCP, the first thing to check is to make sure you've disabled Nagle's algorithm on your sockets; otherwise that will add 200 milliseconds of latency right there:  https://blog.karatos.in/a?ID=01550-ccd1446c-6faf-41ed-b049-45a75cec74bb

Comment: I did this but it had little effect on the delay.